# Save filereader result to variable for later use

Tags: json, typescript, file, filereader

I can't find simple answer, but my code is simple.
I tried something like that, but always when i try to console.log my testResult, then i always recieving null. How to save data from file correctly?

```
public getFile(
    sourceFile: File
  ): string {
    let testResult;
    const file = sourceFile[0]
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8")
    fileReader.onloadend = (e) => { 
      testResult = fileReader.result.toString()
    } 
    console.log(testResult)
    return testResult
  }
```

This problem is related to my other topics, main reason is i can't handle load json file, translate them and upload to user. If i can save this file outside onloadend, then i hope i can handle rest of them (other attempts failed, this one blocking me at beginning)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is quite classical and is related to the asynchronous operations. Function which you assign to the `onloadend` request is called only when `loadend` event fires, but the rest of code will not wait for that to happen and will continue execution. So `console.log` will be executed immediately and then `return` will actually return `testResult` while it is still empty.

Firstly, in order to understand what I just said, put the `console.log(testResult)` line inside of your `onloadend` handler:

```
fileReader.onloadend = (e) => { 
  testResult = fileReader.result.toString();
  console.log(testResult);
}
```

At this point `testResult` is not empty and you may continue handling it inside this function. However, if you want your `getFile` method to be really reusable and want it to return the testResult and process it somewhere else, you need to wrap this method into a Promise, like this:

```
public getFile(
    sourceFile: File
  ): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const file = sourceFile[0]
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onloadend = (e) => { 
        const testResult = fileReader.result.toString();
        resolve(testResult);
      }
      fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    });
  }
```

Now whereever you need a file you can use the `yourInstance.getFile` method as follows:

```
yourInstance.getFile().then(testResult => {
  // do whatever you need here
  console.log(testResult);
});
```

Or in the async/await way:

```
async function processResult() {
  const testResult = await yourInstance.getFile();
  // do whatever you need
  console.log(testResult);
}
```

If you are now familiar with promises and/or async/await, please read more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).